# Unable to post tweet from android application

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I am following [this](https://github.com/learnNcode/DemoTwitterImagePost) tutorial for posting tweets with images in my apps. But I am able to do it, there are no error at all. Just `User` and `Password` entities are not available.
I explicitly tried to give the user and password but still its not posting the tweet. 
Following is my main code

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key));
                    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));
                    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(LoginActivity.getAccessToken((context)));
                    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(LoginActivity.getAccessTokenSecret(context));
                    configurationBuilder.setUser("abc");
                    configurationBuilder.setPassword("888888");
                    Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
                    final Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

                    final File file = new File(myUri.toString());

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        private double x;

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            boolean success = true;
                            try {
                                x = Math.random();
                                if (file.exists()) {
                                    StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate("test message");
                                    status.setMedia(file);
                                    twitter.updateStatus(status);
                                }else{
                                    Log.d(TAG, "----- Invalid File ----------");
                                    success = false;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                success = false;
                            }
```

App has all the permissions from manifest as well from twitter dev account. Please help me out here.

Comment: You don't need to add `setUser` and `setPassword`

Comment: tried without `setUser` and `setPassword`